# checking if inputs in a form are set using nodejs

Tags: node.js, forms

Suppose I want to see an input, say **name** is set in a **form** in php, I can do this:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) {
    echo("type in name"); # or something
}
```

Can I do something like that in nodejs this way:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.name == "") {
        res.send('type in name'); // or something
    }
});
```

I'm new to both php and nodejs, so can someone clarify this for me, or provide me with a better/correct solution in nodejs?

I don't want to check if some object has some property, but if the form submitted has the property name set, i.e name is non empty.

Comment: `req.body.hasOwnProperty('name')` is one of the options!

Comment: @Vohuman my question is different, it's related to form data, not some random javascript object

Comment: `req.body` is an object. A regular/plain object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get post data, you need to use [body-parser](http://npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

Then you need a route handler for handling the post data.

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    // if you set up body parser correctly, all your form data will be accessible in `req.body`
    console.log(req.body) ; 

    const errors = validate(req);

    if(errors.length) {
        // show errors

        return;
    }

    // do something with form data.
});

function validate(req) {
    const errors  = [];

    if (! req.body.firstName) {
        errors.push('First name is required');
    }

    // do the same for all input fields

    return errors;
}
```

Comment: @Vohuman - How does it not? He wanted a way to check post params.